# R: Encoding issues when installing package from Github

Tags: r, devtools

I am trying to install the [`dcStockR`](https://github.com/yutannihilation/dcStockR) package from Github, which is an [`htmlwidgets`](http://www.htmlwidgets.org/) wrapper around the [`dc.js`](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/) dimensional visualization library: `devtools::install_github("yutannihilation/dcStockR")`.

I get the following encoding error:

```
* installing *source* package 'dcStockR' ...
** R
Error in parse(outFile) : 
  C:/Users/tirthankarc/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmpcz8pHX/devtools153839438c/yutannihilation-dcStockR-c6091c8/R/dc.R:11:59: unexpected input
10: #' @export
11: dc <- function(data, chartRecipe = c("yearlyBubbleChart",ã€
                                                              ^
ERROR: unable to collate and parse R files for package 'dcStockR'
* removing 'C:/Users/tirthankarc/Documents/R/R-3.2.5/library/dcStockR'
Error: Command failed (1)
```

The offending lines of the file in question can be viewed here: https://github.com/yutannihilation/dcStockR/blob/master/R/dc.R#L11.

Two questions:

- Is this error reproducible for others?
- If so, is there a way to fix this by passing an explicit encoding option to `install.packages`? If not, what other options are available to fix this issue?

Comment: Submit as an issue on GitHub, the author seems to be active recently. Yes, I am getting the same error. R version 3.3.0.

Comment: @zx8754 Thanks, just did that here: https://github.com/yutannihilation/dcStockR/issues/1.

Comment: Maybe close this post?

Comment: @zx8754 Think that this has general utility as to what to do when handling weirdly encoded packages from GH. Others may disagree -- I can already see one close vote. I will let that process take its course.

Comment: I am not familiar with github and how to commit issue fixes. So i have forked the repo. It should work for you if you try this `devtools::install_github("dimitris1ps/dcStockR")`

Comment: @dimitris_ps create a pull request, if author agrees with your changes, it will be merged to author's repo.

Comment: Thanks @zx8754 just did.

Comment: While this is also an encoding problem (no encoding declared in `DESCRIPTION` file), the more immediate issue is that the stray character in the code is simply wrong: instead of a space, the author used the Unicode character “IDEOGRAPHIC SPACE” (in UTF-8), which is probably a mistake.

Comment: @dimitris_ps Thanks, that installs cleanly. Can you please highlight the changes you made to make this work? That should suffice as an answer to this question.

Comment: @dimitris_ps I see based on [your last commit](https://github.com/dimitris1ps/dcStockR/commit/f09e36201994853c8eee4561effa70260187f117), that you just manually replaced the "spaces" with spaces. Weird how that was the only part of the code that had the weird space characters.